# Posting url through Facebook Graph API does not embed the url, just puts it as a url

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook, facebook-graph-api, python-3.10

I am trying to post a URL to wall. Usually, when you post by hand it will load and include a snippet with the title, image, and byline. This does not happen with my API call. Using Python 3.10, with the facebook-sdk.

```
def post(self, article):
    print(f"\n\n[FacebookPoster] Posting on Facebook:\n\n\"{article.post}\"\n\n")
    self.graph.put_object(parent_object="me", connection_name="feed", message=article.post)
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `link` parameter to pass your URL.

If I modify your code, it should give something like:

```py
def post(self, article):
  print(f"\n\n[FacebookPoster] Posting on Facebook:\n\n{article.post}\n\n")
  self.graph.put_object(parent_object="me", connection_name="feed", message=article.post, link=article.link)
```

Comment: You're a beast. Had to rearrange the object but overall works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help you and have a nice day.